# Selenium2's Select object not firing onchange event in IE8

Tags: java, internet-explorer-8, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

In my app I have two `<select>` tags. The first one changes the options inside the second one and enables it in the onchange event.

When I use the Select object provided by Selenium2 it doesn't fire that event when running in IE8 (works great in FF and when I do it manually).

```
Select select = new Select(getElementByName(name));
element.selectByValue(value);
```

The first `<select>` changes as expected. However, the second `<select>` remains empty and disabled. I tried this as a workaround:

```
if(ie) {
    WebElement select = getElementByName(name);
    WebElement option = select.findElement(By.cssSelector("[value='"+value+"']"));

    List<WebElement> options = select.findElements(By.cssSelector("option"));
    //select the first element
    options.get(0).click();

    //make sure the select is focused
    select.click(); //open
    select.click(); //close

    Keyboard keyboard = getWebDriver().getKeyboard();
    for(int i = 0; i < options.size() && option.getAttribute("selected") == null; i++) {
         keyboard.pressKey(Keys.DOWN);
         //note: if i do a Thread.sleep(100); here, it works more consistently, but still not 100%
    }
} else {
     // Do the above snippet
}
```

but now I get inconsistent results. The desired `<option>` always gets selected, while only sometimes does the event get fired.

Obviously the best option is getting the Select to work in IE8. Has anyone else seen this issue? Seems like a bug in Selenium2. Is there a known workaround for this?

Comment: I haven't had this exact issue, but I have had issues where Selenium works most of the time, but sometimes it fails most of the time due to the element not being present on the page yet. I wrote a method that waits for the element to load and then try again. If it fails again, I automatically re-test if it fails. Not optimal, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After talking with some of the Selenium folk in the #selenium IRC chat room I settled on this fix:

```
WebElement selectElement = getElementByName(name);
Select select = new Select(selectElement);
element.selectByValue(value);
if(usingIE) {
    webDriver.executeScript("$(arguments[0]).fireEvent('change');", selectElement);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are already implementing the SelectElement class so have you tried this

```
WebElement element = getElementByName(name);
element.FindElement(By.CssSelector("option[value='" + value + "']").Select();
```

Answer (score 0):

Am using below code to select a value in 'Country' list (once 'Country' value is selected, corresponding 'State' list is loading):

```
WebElement selectCountry = driver.findElement(By.id("country"));
List<WebElement> options = selectCountry.findElements(By.tagName("option"));
for(WebElement option : options){
    if(option.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("India")){
        option.click();
        break;
    }
}
```

Note - This select operation takes much more time IE when compare to FF. You may need to increase command timeout time using driver.manage().